# Why is my code not adding one to the current Price of the book?

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

```
public void addDollarToRatingOfFour() {
        double one = 1.0;
        double newBookPrice = 0.0;
        for (Book currBook : this.listOfBooks) {
            if (currBook.getRating() > 4) {
                newBookPrice = one + currBook.getPrice();
            }
            newBookPrice = newBookPrice + 1;
        }
    }
```

With this code it is supposed to add a dollar to all the books with a rating of 4 or above, but in my testing it's not adding a dollar at all to any price. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should currBook.setPrice(newcalculatedprice) after recalculating

Answer (score 0):

This looks as though you have this code:
1        double one = 1.0;
2        double newBookPrice = 0.0;
3        for (Book currBook : this.listOfBooks) {
4             if (currBook.getRating() > 4) {
5                  newBookPrice = one + currBook.getPrice();
6              }
7             newBookPrice = newBookPrice + 1;
8        }
9   }

Your object of a book is currBook, which is independent of newBookPrice.
So if you want to set its value, you need to modify the property or field value
 of that object. You are only setting newBookPrice on line 5 above. This is a different variable, not related to the book object -> currBook

You want something like this on line 5:
currBook.Price = currBook.GetPrice() + one;

Additionally, if you are using get/set methods to not access the properties
 directly, then you want to do something like this:
currBook.SetPrice(currBook.GetPrice() + one);

Finally, it may have happened during testing, but you added 1 again on line 7. You want to remove this line.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is updating a local variable called `newBookPrice`.  It is not updating the price of the actual books.   The local variable then gets thrown away when your method returns.

We can't see your `Book` class, but I *expect* that it has a `setPrice(...)` method.  You should be calling that to update the prices of each `Book` object that needs updating.